# Best way to set up a new database on a new server which periodically refreshes tables from a live SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, google-cloud-storage, rdbms

I need to create a database solely for analytical purposes. The idea here is for it to start off as a 1:1 replica of a current SQL Server database but we will then add in additional tables. The idea here is to be able to have read-write access to a db without dropping anything in production inadvertently.

We would ideally like to set a daily refresh schedule to update all tables in the new tb to match the tables in the live environment.

In terms of the DBMS for the new database, I am very easy - MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL would be great -- I am not hugely familiar with the Google Storage/BigQuery stack but if this is an easy option, I'm open to it.

Comment: Is the source database SQL Server? You can simply take last night backup and restore it. I suggest you put your additional tables in a different database. You can still join and reference across databases.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a standard HA/DR solution with a readable secondary (Availability Groups/mirroring /log shipping).
then have a second database on the new server for your additional tables.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) are not RDBMS services themselves, but could be used in this case to store the backups/exports/dumps from the replica, and then have the analytical work performed on those backups.

Here is an example workflow:

1. [Perform a backup and restore in a different database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-sql-server-databases?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. Add the new tables in the new database
3. Export the database as a CSV file on your local machine
4. Here you could either [directly load the CSV file in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local), or [upload that file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) in a Cloud Storage [bucket previously created](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets)
5. [Query the data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/query-overview)

I suggest to take a look at the multiple methods for [loading data in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data), as well as the methods for [querying against external data sources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources) which may help to determine which database replication/export method might be best for your use case.